# How can I set different class for div cheking the json data

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

How can I check true or false from json and put different css for div if true or false:

For example json:

```
{
    "Object": [
    {
        "test": true,
        "number": "001"
    }, {
        "test": false,
        "number": "002"
    }, {
        "test": false,
        "number": "003"
    }, {
        "test": true,
        "number": "004"
    }]
}
```

and i created html:

```
<div class="test" id="001">001</div>
<div class="test" id="002">002</div>
<div class="test" id="003">003</div>
<div class="test" id="004">004</div>
```

I tried something like this but it is wrong...

```
if (test == 'true') {
$(".test").css("background-color", "blue");
} else {
$(".test").css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Comment: paste your full js please!!

Comment: This was in part caused by `test == 'true'` always evaluating to false, because `true != 'true'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(json.Object, function(index, value) {
    $number = $("#"+value.number);
    if(value.test) $number.css("background-color", "blue");
    else $number.css("background-color", "red");
});
```

or

```
$.each(json.Object, function(index, value) {
    $("#"+value.number).css("background-color", (value.test ? "blue" : "red"));
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eSeDu/)

Comment: you want toggle black and default color?

Comment: toogle only on blue background-color..i tried with code below on your fiddle click works on every div...

Answer (score 0):

if I can continue on this question...how can I set clicks only on div with blue background-color and disable click on red div?

```
$.each(json.Object, function (index, value) {
            $("#" + value.number).css("background-color", (value.test ? "blue" : "red"));
                    $(".test").click(function (event) {
                            $("#" + value.number).css("background-color", (value.test ? "blue" : "red"));                       
                            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
                        });        
        });
```